# what does "as much as you please" mean

Tags: sentence

What does

> as much as you please.

mean ?

I tried to search the word *please* but I still can't understand what is "as much as you please" mean

Comment: Related: [The word "please" in "if you please"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/138617/41273)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should ask "What *does* it mean?"

*Please* is a verb here, so it means simply *as much as you want* or *would like*.

See [this definition](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/please_2).

Answer (score 3):

As much as you please" means as much or as little as the person desires. It's a phrase often used to indicate that there is no limit or restriction on the amount of something that someone can have or do. It is polite to say that the person has complete freedom to choose the quantity or extent of something.

Comment: complete freedom to choose the quantity or extent of something, thank you.